# Array of Arrays to an Array of Unique Values Using Reduce/Map

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array of arrays, that needs to become 1 array of unique values.

```
[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]
```

I want to use reduce/map to solve the problem, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have solved the problem already with nested for loops like so:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++) {
      if (!arr.includes(args[i][j])) {
        arr.push(args[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Now I tried to solve the problem here using reduce/map, but not getting the correct solution, like so:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  return args.reduce(
    (arr, a) => a.map(n => (!arr.includes(n) ? arr.push(n) : n)),
    []
  );
}
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

I also tried to solve with reduce/map, using the older syntax, like so:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  return args.reduce(function(arr, a) {
    return a.map(function(n) {
      if (!arr.includes(n)) {
        return arr.push(n);
      } else {
        return n;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

My guess is that I'm not doing something right with the return statements in the callback functions. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that:

```
 arr.includes(n)
```

`arr` is an array of arrays, includes wont work there. You also never pass `arr` down the reduce chain.

---

The easiest to solve would be:

```
  [...new Set(array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []))]
```

That just flattens the array, builds a Set for uniqueness and spreads it into an array. Or another elegant solution usong iterators:

```
 function* flatten(arr) {
   for(const el of arr) {
      if(Array.isArray(el)) {
        yield* flatten(el);
      } else {
       yield el;
     }
   }
}

const result = [];

 for(const el of flatten(array))
   if(!result.includes(el)) result.push(el);
```

Comment: can you add a bit of explanation your solution looks really nice and short

Comment: Actually I think arr is my empty array declared in the initial reduce, whereas args is my array of arrays.

Comment: @jhazelton1 yes you are right. You confused me with the weird function argument.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `array#map` use `array#forEach` and push unique number in the accumulator.

```js
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  return args.reduce((arr, a) => {
    a.forEach(n => (!arr.includes(n) ? arr.push(n) : n));
    return arr
  },[]);
}
console.log(uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
```

Alternatively, you can `array#concat` all the array and then using `Set` get the unique value.

```js
const arr = [[1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]],
      unique = [...new Set([].concat(...arr))];
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Can you explain why array#forEach works here instead of array#map?

Comment: Even the `array#map` would have worked but `array#map` was returning the new value for each iteration which was overwriting the old result. So, what you require was an accumulator and checking your number wrt to this accumulator. So, instead of returning the result of `array#map`, you had to return the value of accumultor.